# Vuex Store- call another action which MUST complete before code resumes execution

Tags: javascript, vuex, store, pause

Thanks in advance. So here's a simplified view of what I'm trying to achieve: I have the main async action in my Vuex store that calls another action in the same Vuex store. I need the mainCodeBlock code to wait for the called, second action to complete before it continues execution. Any thoughts? Example code below:

```
export const actions = {

//main code
async mainCodeBlock(vuexContext, someData) {

    vuexContext.dispatch("theCodeThatMustFinishBeforeTheMainCodeResumes")
    //this code cannot continue until the called code above completes
    ...

}

//code I'm calling that needs to complete before the main code continues
async theCodeThatMustFinishBeforeTheMainCodeResumes(vuexContext) {
    //this code does stuff that needs to complete BEFORE returning to main code
    //it can return a value but it doesn't have to...
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can use a store variable to change on theCodeThatMustFinishBeforeTheMainCodeResumes is finished(commit a mutation), and observe the variable inside a component(using getters in computed). Put a watch on that variable and based on updation dispatch the action mainCodeBlock.